# Integrate Joomla CSS system with Twitter-Bootstrap CSS

Tags: css, joomla, twitter-bootstrap, joomla2.5

It's less that 24 hours that I've known Bootstrap and I've fallen in love into it!

As I've understood, Bootstrap is a collection of CSSs ready to use.

We should only give the class name according to Bootstrap and our website will have a modern and perfect look.

OK.

Now the problem is that Joomla builtin system doesn't use **Bootstrap compatible** classes.

Is there a fast way to change way to change Joomla builtin CSS system to be compatible with Bootstrap?

Hope it be understandable.

Maybe there is a plugin to convert Joomla CSS system to Bootstrap-familiar CSS. I couldn't find such exact plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know the feeling about Bootstrap. A lot of people would disagree, but I too really like it. However, even though Joomla 3.0 is based on Bootstrap, I wouldn't recommend using it, as it's the short release. Joomla 2.5 is still the long term recommended version to use, therefore I suggest you stick with that and find yourself a Boostrap template, such as [Joomstrap](https://github.com/A973C/Joomstrap), which is free. Please note that the template was based on Bootstrap 2.0.4, so you will need to download the latest version and replace the *CSS* and *JS* files.

You might also be interested in the [Boostrap template based on Gantry for Joomla 2.5](https://github.com/anibalsanchez/jbootstrap/tree/0.6.0-gantry4).

Having said to stick with Joomla 2.5 as it's the long term release, once Joomla 3.5 comes out, which will be the next long term release, I would upgrade to that. This too will also be based on Bootstrap.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. Yes, now that I upgraded from 2.5.8 to 3.0.2, I can see that the CSS has been broken. +1 for your useful answer. I set this answer as the best :)

Comment: Hate to say it but the template you recommended says at the bottom "The current version is a "Work in Progress". Feel free to use it for testing only!" which kinda defeats the purpose of using a Joomla 2.5 stable interface. CSS would only be broken if your functions weren't Joomla 3.0 compat. 3.0 is prefectly stable however you'd just have to stay on the upgrade path until 3.5 is reached. There is nothing wrong with using it.

Comment: never said there was anything wrong with using Joomla 3.0. As stated, Joomla 2.5 is the recommended release, more popular, more available fopr it (extension wise) etc. The template I provided was an example, hence the "such as" before it. There will be others out and about.

Answer (score 2):

If it's possible for you to upgrade your System, the new Joomla 3.0 comes with Bootstrap. Otherwise you only have to build an own Template where you use this Framework.

Comment: Do you mean that default Joomla 3.0 components, are using Bootstrap? Very well!

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with doing that.
You **start with developing a custom template**, then after that you just use **overrides** for your **components** etc.

You don't need a plugin.

Comment: by (overrides for your components), do you mean creating a `components` folder in my template and bringing all needed components and change their classes in each view that I have used in my website?

Comment: You can start here:
http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core

Comment: Make an html folder in your template (not components) and then inside that the name of the component, name of view and then put your replacement layout file(s). Look in your template folder to see examples

/templates/templatename/html/componentname/viewname/default.php

templates/beez_20/html/com_contact/contact/default.php